# How to preserve red color only using ImageMagick command line

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have the following image:

[image]

What I want is to preserve only red color and desaturate
every other color into grayscale. Resulting in this:

[image]

How can I do that with Imagemagick command line?

I tried this but failed:

```
convert original.png \( -clone 0  -transparent red -alpha extract -transparent black \) redonly.png
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way, though not perfect, using ImageMagick. I specify hue=0 deg for red and tolerance=25 deg both in range 0 to 360.

Input:

[image]

```
hue=0
tolerance=25
toler=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:(100*$tolerance/360)]" info:`
hueval=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:50-$hue]" info:`
thresh=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:100-$tolerance]" info:`
convert tomato.jpg \
\( -clone 0 -colorspace gray -colorspace sRGB \) \
\( -clone 0 -colorspace HSL -channel 0 -separate +channel \
-evaluate AddModulus ${hueval}% \
-solarize 50% -level 0x50% \
-threshold $thresh% \) \
-swap 0,1 -alpha off -compose over -composite \
result.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also not perfect, but fairly easy to understand. Basically, you could use the [fx operator](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fx) to inspect the Hue of each pixel and, depending on its Hue/colour, return either the original pixel or its greyscale equivalent.

So, as a first stab, you might do this to replace all pixels exhibiting a high Hue value with their greyscale (lightness) equivalent:

```
magick ripe.jpg -fx "(u.hue<0.1)? u : u.lightness" result.jpg
```

[image]

Then you might realise that red Hues wrap around at 0/360 degrees on the Hue circle, so you could do:

```
magick ripe.jpg -fx "(u.hue<0.1)||(u.hue>0.9)? u : u.lightness" result.jpg
```

[image]

**Explanation**

There are a couple of things going on here. Firstly, the `-fx` operator is a very low-level, extremely powerful (and sadly rather slow because it is interpreted) way of running a piece of *"code"* on every pixel in the image. Secondly, I am running a ternary operator with the format:

```
condition? valueA : valueB
```

so I am testing a condition for every pixel, and if true I return `valueA`, and if false I return `valueB`. When I refer to `u` and `u.hue` and `u.lightness`, the `u` means the *first* image in my command - I could load two images and use features of the first to select features of the second, then I would use `u` and `v` to differentiate. Finally, the values are scaled on the range [0,1] so I don't test for *"Hue>350 in the range [0,360]"*, instead I test for `Hue>0.9` as a sloppy equivalent - I guess I could have used `Hue>(350/360)`. Note that you can make the expression arbitrarily complicated and also put it in a separate file to re-use it like this:

```
magick ripe.jpg -fx @DeSatNonRed.fx  result.jpg
```

`DeSatNonRed.fx` might look something like this:

```
hueMin=350/360;
hueMax=20/360;
(hue>hueMin) || (hue<hueMax) ? u : u.lightness
```

Note that, in the general case, you should also really consider Saturation when looking at Hues, which you can add in above, but which I omitted for clarity, and because your image is almost fully saturated anyway.

**Keywords**: Image processing, ImageMagick, low-level fx operator, ternary, pixel-by-pixel, evaluate, expression.

Comment: `@Mark` my code is essentially doing the same thing. The solarize, then offset, then threshold is doing the same kind of thing as your fx expression, but in degrees. I did not give much explanation, so thanks for doing that in a simple way.

Comment: When I try the above code `magick ripe.jpg -fx "(u.hue<0.1)||(u.hue>0.9)? u : u.lightness" result.jpg` I see no noticeable change to the image of tomatoes (ripe.jpg). Any idea why this may be? I'm using Windows 10 and IM v7.1.1-24 .

Comment: @Rez99 The altered file is saved as `"result.jpg"`

Comment: Yes, I meant that I see no noticeable change between ripe.jpg and result.jpg.

Comment: @Rez99 Try just making it solid white with `magick input.png -fx "1" result.png` and solid just black with `magick input.png -fx "0" result.png` to see if your installation is working.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, I get solid white and solid black from those code snippets.

Comment: @Rez99 Did you use the exact images from the question? Or did you use your own, similar images? Can you try making a greyscale version with `-fx "u.lightness"` ?

Comment: I used the exact images (I downloaded them from this question). When I run `magick ripe.jpg -fx "u.lightness" grey.jpg` - the input and output images seem identical.

Comment: @Rez99 Mmmm... I'm stuck. Maybe try `u.hue` and see if you can get different shades for different colours. What OS are you using and which **ImageMagick** version?